# Calling startKoin() once before launching all unit tests and stopKoin() once after all tests finish

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, junit, koin

I have several test classes implementing `KoinTest` interface, and in every one of them I have the same code:

```
@Before
fun setUp() {
    startKoin { modules(appModule) }
}

@After
fun tearDown() {
    stopKoin()
}
```

**Is it possible to call `startKoin()` before all these tests, and after the tests call `stopKoin()`, so I can remove above code from every test class?** Or maybe it would be strongly discouraged for some reason?

I see that in [docs here](https://insert-koin.io/docs/2.0/getting-started/junit-test/) they have written '*For each test, we start startKoin() and close Koin context closeKoin().*', but I don't know if this is the only valid way to go.

Comment: I usually aim for constructor dependency injection so that tests don't need an object graph at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `TestRule`. Create a test rule for `Koin`.

```
class KoinTestRule : TestRule {

   override fun apply(base: Statement, description: Description): Statement {
       return object : Statement() {

           override fun evaluate() {

               startKoin { modules(appModule) }

               base.evaluate()

               stopKoin()
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Create `BaseKoinTest` that implements `KoinTest` interface and add the rule to this class. All the test classes that require `Koin` can extend from this class.

```
abstract class BaseKoinTest : KoinTest {

    @get:Rule
    val koinTestRule = KoinTestRule()
}
```